# How to hover over whole shape created with pseudo selectors?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply shadow to the whole shape. But the shape defined with ::after is not affected. How do i work with the shape as a unit?

style.css

```
.diag{
   position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 100px;
   width: 150px;
   height: 90px;
   background-color: gray;
   border-radius: 10px;

}

.diag::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: 35px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}

 .diag:hover{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
```

Comment: Share your html code as well.

Comment: filter:drop-sahdow instead of box-shadow

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am a little curious now, i tried ' transform: rotate(); ' and that worked with the whole shape. Is there anything i should know more?

Comment: when you apply a transform to an element it get applied to that element and all its content. It like applying opacity, display:none, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
.diag {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.diag::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 35px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}

.diag:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="diag">

</div>
```